Delayed clipboard rendering of multiple files
Working in .NET 8 on Windows (net8.0-windows), I'd like to put several files on the clipboard but only provide the actual data once the user pastes.
This seems straightforward: I subclass DataObject and override the GetData function, handling the two relevant formats ("FileGroupDescriptorW" and "FileContents"):
private class MyDataObject : DataObject
{
    public override object GetData(string format, bool autoConvert)
    {
        if (string.Compare(format, CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = // Create a FileGroupDescriptorW, get the bytes and create a memory stream
            base.SetData(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW, ms);
        }
        else if (string.Compare(format, CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {      
            // pseudo-code, I have a stream implementation that will provide the file bytes
            base.SetData(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, new MyVirtualFileStream());
        }

    return base.GetData(format, autoConvert);
}

And I simply drop my data object on the clipboard:
MyDataObject appDataObject = new();
appDataObject.SetData(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW, null);
appDataObject.SetData(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS, null);
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject(appDataObject);

So far, so good; and this works great if I have a single file. I paste in Windows Explorer and my file is pasted successfully.
But what if I have multiple files? i.e. FileGroupDescriptorW has a count greater than 1. There is no way to get the index that's requested in GetData or any of its overloads.
In the COM equivalent IDataObject, FORMATETC has the lindex property that gives this information, but it doesn't seem there is anything equivalent on .NET. Is this truly not possible in managed code?
I'm looking for a clear example of how to implement this.
ChatGPT suggested simply storing an index and incrementing it manually, but as far as I can tell there is nothing that suggest Windows will request the file contents in sequential order.
ChatGPT further suggested dropping down to COM to achieve this; which I'm fine with if it works. But even after implementing a barebones System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject and trying to assign it to the clipboard with either SetDataObject or OleSetClipboard; I immediately get an access violation (without even hitting any of the code in my skeleton class - makes me think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong).
Can anyone suggest a path forward on how to achieve this?

See if you can benefit from this article. Specifically, how to process multiple files. Drag/drop and copy/paste operations are handled the same way.

Thanks for the link @dr.null, I'll take a look!

The .NET-provided DataObjects (WPF & Winforms, and BTW they're not the same wich is kinda dumb...) are really designed for .NET, including .NET objects, etc. they are not designed for general purpose clipboard or copy-paste operations.
Here is some sample C# code that allows you to add on-demand streamable file descriptors to a custom-made native IDataObject, that can itself be added to the clipboard (or to something else). It supports paste from Explorer, from Office apps (Outloook, Word), etc.:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing; // just used for SIZE and POINT struct that could be rewritten if Winforms is not desired
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Windows.Forms; // just used for MessageBox in caller's code

namespace OnDemandDataObject;

internal class Program
{
    [STAThread] // calling thread must be STA
    static void Main()
    {
        using var da = new DataObject();
        da.SetOnDemandFiles([
            FileDescriptor.FromFile(@"d:\temp\first.pdf"),
            FileDescriptor.FromFile(@"d:\temp\second.txt")
            // etc.
            ]);
        da.SetToClipboard();
        // runs message pump in this console app sample
        MessageBox.Show("Press ok to remove files from the clipboard"); 
    }
}

public class FileDescriptor()
{
    // this is what's called on-demand when a stream is asked for reading (on paste action)
    public virtual Func<Stream>? GetStream { get; set; } 
    public virtual FILEDESCRIPTOR Descriptor { get; set; }

    // utility to create a descriptor from a file
    // but could be adapted for network streams, etc.
    public static FileDescriptor FromFile(string filePath, Func<Stream>? getStream = null) { ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(filePath); return FromFile(new FileInfo(filePath), getStream); }
    public static FileDescriptor FromFile(FileInfo info, Func<Stream>? getStream = null)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(info);
        var fd = new FileDescriptor();
        fd.GetStream ??= () => new FileStream(info.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        fd.Descriptor = FILEDESCRIPTOR.FromFileInfo(info);
        return fd;
    }
}

public class DataObject : DataObject.IDataObject, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<(FORMATETC, STGMEDIUM, bool)> _data = [];
    private bool _disposedValue;

    // can't use Winforms Clipboard.SetData with a custom IDataObject
    public virtual void SetToClipboard()
    {
        OleInitialize(0);
        OleSetClipboard(this);
    }

    public virtual void SetOnDemandFiles(IReadOnlyList<FileDescriptor> files)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(files);
        if (files.Count == 0)
            return;

        if (files.Any(d => d.GetStream == null))
            throw new ArgumentException(null, nameof(files));

        // build CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW
        var elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FILEDESCRIPTOR>();
        var size = Marshal.SizeOf<int>() + elementSize * files.Count;
        var fileDescriptorsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        var current = fileDescriptorsPtr;
        Marshal.WriteInt32(current, files.Count);
        current += Marshal.SizeOf<int>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(file.Descriptor, current, false);
            current += elementSize;
        }

        try
        {
            // set CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW
            var fmt = new FORMATETC { dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT, cfFormat = (short)RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW), lindex = -1, tymed = TYMED.TYMED_HGLOBAL };
            var medium = new STGMEDIUM { tymed = fmt.tymed, unionmember = fileDescriptorsPtr };
            ((IDataObject)this).SetData(ref fmt, ref medium, true);

            // set all CFSTR_FILECONTENTS
            var format = RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS);
            fmt = new FORMATETC { dwAspect = DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT, cfFormat = (short)format, tymed = TYMED.TYMED_ISTREAM };
            medium = new STGMEDIUM { tymed = fmt.tymed };
            for (var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                fmt.lindex = i;
                var stream = new ReadStream(files[i]);
                var unk = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(stream, typeof(IStream));
                try
                {
                    medium.unionmember = unk;
                    medium.pUnkForRelease = stream;
                    ((IDataObject)this).SetData(ref fmt, ref medium, true);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.Release(unk);
                }
            }
        }
        catch // free only on error
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(fileDescriptorsPtr);
            throw;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                foreach (var data in _data.Where(d => d.Item3))
                {
                    var medium = data.Item2;
                    ReleaseStgMedium(ref medium);
                }
                _data.Clear();
            }
            _disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    ~DataObject() { Dispose(disposing: false); }
    public void Dispose() { Dispose(disposing: true); GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }

    int IDataObject.GetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetcIn, out STGMEDIUM pmedium)
    {
        foreach (var data in _data)
        {
            if (data.Item1.cfFormat == pformatetcIn.cfFormat && data.Item1.lindex == pformatetcIn.lindex)
            {
                var medium = data.Item2;
                return CopyStgMediumOut(ref medium, out pmedium);
            }
        }

        pmedium = new();
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    }

    int IDataObject.GetDataHere(ref FORMATETC pformatetcIn, ref STGMEDIUM pmedium)
    {
        foreach (var data in _data)
        {
            if (data.Item1.cfFormat == pformatetcIn.cfFormat && data.Item1.lindex == pformatetcIn.lindex)
            {
                var medium = data.Item2;
                medium.pUnkForRelease = 0;
                return CopyStgMediumRef(ref medium, ref pmedium);
            }
        }
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    }

    int IDataObject.QueryGetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetc)
    {
        foreach (var data in _data)
        {
            if (data.Item1.cfFormat == pformatetcIn.cfFormat && data.Item1.lindex == pformatetcIn.lindex)
                return 0;
        }
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    }

    int IDataObject.SetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetc, ref STGMEDIUM pmedium, bool fRelease)
    {
        foreach (var data in _data.ToArray())
        {
            if (data.Item1.cfFormat == pformatetc.cfFormat && data.Item1.lindex == pformatetc.lindex)
            {
                _data.Remove(data);
            }
        }
        _data.Add((pformatetc, pmedium, fRelease));
        return 0;
    }

    int IDataObject.GetCanonicalFormatEtc(ref FORMATETC pformatectIn, out FORMATETC pformatetcOut) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    int IDataObject.EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR dwDirection, out IEnumFORMATETC ppenumFormatEtc) { ppenumFormatEtc = new EnumFORMATETC(this, dwDirection); return 0; }
    int IDataObject.DAdvise(ref FORMATETC pformatetc, uint advf, IAdviseSink pAdvSink, out uint dwConnection) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    int IDataObject.DUnadvise(uint dwConnection) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    int IDataObject.EnumDAdvise(out IEnumSTATDATA ppenumAdvise) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    private sealed class EnumFORMATETC(DataObject dataObject, DATADIR direction) : IEnumFORMATETC
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public int Next(int celt, FORMATETC[] rgelt, int[] pceltFetched)
        {
            if (pceltFetched != null) { pceltFetched[0] = 0; }
            if (Index >= dataObject._data.Count)
                return 1;

            var fetched = 0;
            while (fetched < celt && fetched < dataObject._data.Count)
            {
                rgelt[fetched] = dataObject._data[Index].Item1;
                Index++;
                fetched++;
            }

            if (pceltFetched != null) { pceltFetched[0] = fetched; }
            return fetched == celt ? 0 : 1;
        }

        public int Reset() { Index = 0; return 0; }
        public void Clone(out IEnumFORMATETC newEnum) => newEnum = new EnumFORMATETC(dataObject, direction);
        public int Skip(int celt) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private sealed class ReadStream : IStream
    {
        private readonly FileDescriptor _descriptor;
        private readonly Lazy<Stream> _stream;

        public ReadStream(FileDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            _descriptor = descriptor;
            _stream = new Lazy<Stream>(() => _descriptor.GetStream!() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException());
        }

        private Stream Stream => _stream.Value;

        // Explorer calls here
        void IStream.Read(byte[] pv, int cb, nint pcbRead)
        {
            var read = Stream.Read(pv, 0, cb);
            if (pcbRead != 0) { Marshal.WriteInt32(pcbRead, read); }
        }

        void IStream.Seek(long dlibMove, int dwOrigin, nint plibNewPosition)
        {
            var newPos = Stream.Seek(dlibMove, (SeekOrigin)dwOrigin);
            if (plibNewPosition != 0) { Marshal.WriteInt64(plibNewPosition, newPos); }
        }

        public void Stat(out STATSTG pstatstg, int grfStatFlag)
        {
            const int STGTY_STREAM = 2;
            const int STGM_READWRITE = 2;
            const int STGM_WRITE = 1;
            var stream = Stream;
            pstatstg = new STATSTG { type = STGTY_STREAM, cbSize = stream.Length, };

            const int STATFLAG_NONAME = 1;
            if ((grfStatFlag & STATFLAG_NONAME) == 0) pstatstg.pwcsName = _descriptor.Descriptor.cFileName;
            pstatstg.atime = ToFileTime(_descriptor.Descriptor.ftLastAccessTime);
            pstatstg.ctime = ToFileTime(_descriptor.Descriptor.ftCreationTime);
            pstatstg.mtime = ToFileTime(_descriptor.Descriptor.ftLastWriteTime);
            pstatstg.clsid = _descriptor.Descriptor.clsid;

            if (stream.CanRead && stream.CanWrite)
            {
                pstatstg.grfMode |= STGM_READWRITE;
                return;
            }

            if (stream.CanWrite) { pstatstg.grfMode |= STGM_WRITE; }
        }

        // Office (outlook, word, etc.) calls here
        public void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, nint pcbRead, nint pcbWritten)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(pstm);
            var count = 0L;
            var bytes = new byte[0x14000]; // 81920 under loh
            do
            {
                var max = (int)Math.Min(cb - count, bytes.Length);
                var read = Stream.Read(bytes, 0, max);
                if (read == 0)
                    break;

                pstm.Write(bytes, read, 0);
                count += read;
                if (count == cb)
                    break;
            }
            while (true);

            if (pcbRead != 0) Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbRead, count);
            if (pcbWritten != 0) Marshal.WriteInt64(pcbWritten, count);

            pstm.Commit(0); // STGC_DEFAULT
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pstm); // we must do this otherwise Office doesn't like it
        }

        public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags) => Stream.Flush();
        void IStream.Write(byte[] pv, int cb, nint pcbWritten) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        void IStream.SetSize(long libNewSize) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        void IStream.Revert() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        void IStream.LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        void IStream.UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        void IStream.Clone(out IStream ppstm) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        private static FILETIME ToFileTime(long fileTime) => new() { dwLowDateTime = (int)(fileTime & uint.MaxValue), dwHighDateTime = (int)(fileTime >> 32) };
    }

    private const int DV_E_FORMATETC = unchecked((int)0x80040064);
    private const string CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW = "FileGroupDescriptorW";
    private const string CFSTR_FILECONTENTS = "FileContents";

    [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int RegisterClipboardFormat(string format);

    [DllImport("ole32")]
    private static extern int OleSetClipboard(IDataObject pDataObj);

    [DllImport("ole32")]
    private static extern int OleInitialize(nint pvReserved);

    [DllImport("ole32")]
    private static extern void ReleaseStgMedium(ref STGMEDIUM medium);

    [DllImport("urlmon", EntryPoint = "CopyStgMedium")]
    private static extern int CopyStgMediumOut(ref STGMEDIUM pcstgmedSrc, out STGMEDIUM pstgmedDest);

    [DllImport("urlmon", EntryPoint = "CopyStgMedium")]
    private static extern int CopyStgMediumRef(ref STGMEDIUM pcstgmedSrc, ref STGMEDIUM pstgmedDest);

    [ComImport, Guid("0000010E-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IDataObject // redefined so we don't need to throw
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetcIn, out STGMEDIUM pmedium);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDataHere(ref FORMATETC pformatetcIn, ref STGMEDIUM pmedium);
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryGetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetc);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetCanonicalFormatEtc(ref FORMATETC pformatectIn, out FORMATETC pformatetcOut);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetData(ref FORMATETC pformatetc, ref STGMEDIUM pmedium, bool fRelease);
        [PreserveSig]
        int EnumFormatEtc(DATADIR dwDirection, out IEnumFORMATETC ppenumFormatEtc);
        [PreserveSig]
        int DAdvise(ref FORMATETC pformatetc, uint advf, IAdviseSink pAdvSink, out uint dwConnection);
        [PreserveSig]
        int DUnadvise(uint dwConnection);
        [PreserveSig]
        int EnumDAdvise(out IEnumSTATDATA ppenumAdvise);
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct FILEDESCRIPTOR
{
    public FD dwFlags;
    public Guid clsid;
    public Size sizel;
    public Point pointl;
    public FileAttributes dwFileAttributes;
    public long ftCreationTime;
    public long ftLastAccessTime;
    public long ftLastWriteTime;
    public uint nFileSizeHigh;
    public uint nFileSizeLow;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string cFileName;
    public override readonly string ToString() => cFileName;

    public static FILEDESCRIPTOR FromFileInfo(FileInfo info)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(info);
        var fd = new FILEDESCRIPTOR { dwFlags = FD.FD_UNICODE, cFileName = info.Name };
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            fd.dwFlags |= FD.FD_FILESIZE | FD.FD_ATTRIBUTES;
            fd.nFileSizeLow = (uint)(info.Length & uint.MaxValue);
            fd.nFileSizeHigh = (uint)(info.Length >> 32);
            fd.dwFileAttributes = info.Attributes;
            if (IsValidFileTime(info.CreationTimeUtc))
            {
                fd.ftCreationTime = info.CreationTimeUtc.ToFileTimeUtc();
                fd.dwFlags |= FD.FD_CREATETIME;
            }
            if (IsValidFileTime(info.LastAccessTimeUtc))
            {
                fd.ftLastAccessTime = info.LastAccessTimeUtc.ToFileTimeUtc();
                fd.dwFlags |= FD.FD_ACCESSTIME;
            }
            if (IsValidFileTime(info.LastWriteTimeUtc))
            {
                fd.ftLastWriteTime = info.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToFileTimeUtc();
                fd.dwFlags |= FD.FD_WRITESTIME;
            }
        }

        const long fileTimeOffset = 504911232000000000; // daysTo1601 * ticksPerDay;
        static long ToFileTime(DateTime dt) => (dt.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc ? dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks : dt.Ticks) - fileTimeOffset;
        static bool IsValidFileTime(DateTime dt) => ToFileTime(dt) >= 0;
        return fd;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum FD
{
    FD_CLSID = 0x00000001,
    FD_SIZEPOINT = 0x00000002,
    FD_ATTRIBUTES = 0x00000004,
    FD_CREATETIME = 0x00000008,
    FD_ACCESSTIME = 0x00000010,
    FD_WRITESTIME = 0x00000020,
    FD_FILESIZE = 0x00000040,
    FD_PROGRESSUI = 0x00004000,
    FD_LINKUI = 0x00008000,
    FD_UNICODE = unchecked((int)0x80000000),
}


I have to adapt this to my specific case, but after some initial tests it works great. Thank you for a great and detailed answer.
